# How do you feed 'str' data to decision tree without one-hot encoding

Tags: python, parsing, decision-tree

I am working on linguistic data to train a classifier (decision tree). Data is in csv format, tab separated and it has 62000 rows and 11 columns.

Data Sample:

````
target_lemma    target_pos  left_word   left_word_pos   right_word  right_word_pos  parrent_word    parrent_word_pos    arg_word    arg_word_pos    label```

form    VBZ %%  %%  forms   VBZ forms   VBZ forms   VBZ N```

form    VBZ provINce    NN  %%  %%  forms   VBZ forms   VBZ N```

form    VBZ The DT  %%  %%  forms   VBZ provINce    NN  N```
````

- In this data the Null is replaced by %%.
- First 10 values are features
- Last value is the label which is either N or Y.

Decision tree gives an error as it expects the features to be int or float values. To resolve this issue I have encoded the data with one-hot encoder and it works fine on the data which is split in 80,20.

The real problem occurs when I give it a user input without the label. I convert the input into one-hot encoded data and pass it to the predictor.
It gives me a value error saying the number of features does not ma n_features is 11823 and input_features is 10.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

h = FeatureHasher(input_type='string')

balance_data = pd.read_csv('identifier-tab.csv',
                       delimiter='\t',
                       encoding="ISO-8859-1")

# Splitting Dataset
Y = balance_data.label
X = balance_data.drop(columns='label')

X = pd.get_dummies(X)
Y = pd.get_dummies(Y)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=100)
print(X_test)

# Gini
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", random_state=100, max_depth=9, min_samples_leaf=9)
clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf_gini.predict(X_test)
print("Gini Predicted values:")
print(y_pred)
print("Gini Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100)


# Entropy
clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", random_state=100, max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)
clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf_entropy.predict(X_test)
print("Entropy Predicted values:")
print(y_pred)
print("Entropy Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100)

# User Test (DOES NOT WORK)
xx = "present   JJ  peculiar    JJ  %%  %%  written VBN character   NN"
x = xx.split("\t")
data = pd.Series(x)
print(x)
print(data)
data = pd.get_dummies(data)
print(data)

user = clf_gini.predict(data)
```

Any suggestions or code help would be great!

Comment: Try using random forest so each estimator only takes into account a small subset of features

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually use the FeatureHasher you defined? Also I am not sure why you use lower-case x and y in the train_test_split when you define it before in capital letters.

Regarding the problem of your user input. You apply the one-hot-encoding only on your given data which results in an extra feature for each unique value in your categorical features. When you have your user data, you only have one unique value in your categorical features and apply an extra one-hot-encoding which results in only one one-hot-encoded feature. So you should call get_dummies() on the combined data to make sure the encoding matches.

However, I dont think that one-hot-encoding is a good choice here as it seems that your categorical features contain many unique values resulting in a very large amount of features (11823). So you might think about using a OrdinalEncoder, e.g. from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html)

When you don't want to/ or cannot combine user input and your known data, think of adding an extra encoding for "unknown" values.

Comment: I tried to use the FeatureHeader but it didn't work for me. It works on the dictionary data I guess. Can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: Your problem is that you encode your user data separately from your train/test data. This causes that the numbers of feature differ and that your user data cannot be classified. You can find code snippets on scikit-learn for how to use encoders
Please also remove code parts which are not used, next time.